# Trying to override Woocommerce My Account page template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Essentially, I want to remove the registration form on the My Account page. I tried setting up the file structure in my Theme folder and everything looks correct. But when I try to make changes to the template nothing happens.

my-child-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php

This is how I have it setup. Woocommerce detects the override in system status too. I tried adding a class to the register form so that I could hide the form using css but it doesn't appear in the code.

Any clues as to what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any solution to this one? I'm experiencing the same problem. I did clear the cache template on woo but still not working. I'm not sure about the other templates under /my-account because I haven't checked except the form-login.php. mmmm!

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache , define cache false in your wp-config file.

Comment: suspected that and disabled WP Super Cache. Set it to false but still no luck. Do you need more information?

Comment: add_theme_support('woocommerce');

https://docs.woothemes.com/document/declare-woocommerce-support-in-third-party-theme/

Tried this one?

Comment: Tried adding that but no luck. This theme supports woocommerce so I'm guessing it's already been declared. 

http://securityguardcourse.ca/my-courses/

Here's my page if that helps.

Comment: I've got the same problem, is a solution has been found?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Have you tried to put it in main theme with the same structure??
Or is there any woo commerce folder exists in your main theme.

Comment: I tried both yes. I tried using the main theme only. Then I tried the child only. Now I'm trying it with both. Because the theme already comes with some templates overrided. Woocommerce seems to detect both folders no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS in your **style.css** -

```
.entry-content #my-courses .col-2
     {
       display : none;
     }
```

hope this will help you.